# Custom Hyperlinks on Ctrl+Mouseover for custom pattern

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write an extension for vs-code that does the following:

I want to have each of the "XY-#" expressions in the comments of gtests to be highlighted and clickable when holding down ctrl. Each link should open the default browser with an url
`https://website/<number>`
e.g. for the first expression in the example `https://website/1912603`

```
/// @requirement XY-#1912603, XY-#1884770, XY-#1885273
TEST_P(SomeFixture, Foo)
{
    SUCCEED();
}
```

So what I will probably need is

- some kind of regex pattern matching
- code highlighting based on the matched pattern
- reaction to ctrl-key
- Link creation with the parsed and stripped `<number>`

I've been looking around for a while but couldn't find any example extension with a similar usecase. Any one of you came across some good examples to look into?

Thanks in advance,
Flo

Comment: If you don't want to write by yourself, see 'Link Patterns', it should match your criteria (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanLevett.pattern-links)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [registerDocumentLinkProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerDocumentLinkProvider)